# PHP Warning: callback, function 'register_shortcodes' not found or invalid function > name / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to migrate a wordpress site to a new server. When I clone the website to local environment and try to do some testing, i got the following warning message:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'register_shortcodes' not found or invalid function
>   name in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mySite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 286

This is the code of the class-wp-hook.php:

```
// Avoid the array_slice if possible.
if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
} elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args ); //LINE 286
} else {
    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
}
```

I can not find any way to remove this warning, can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried gathering a better stack trace? That would help to spot where the data came from. Additionally, have you checked that the local environment matches the server's in terms of PHP version and settings?

Comment: yes, the local environment is the same as the server environment. How do I compile that information that you tell me?

Comment: you are using `HOOK ` in your project but there you are not passing proper parameters as per Hook needs.

Comment: And how can I locate the problem to solve it? The company that made the web has closed and I can not contact the person who developed it. I just had a backup of the web that works correctly and nothing else

Comment: search for `add_shortcode` in you local files, and then check if all functions that are passed to as a second argument in each instance are actually defined. alternatively you can search `register_shortcodes` in your local files and you will get the corresponding `add_shortcode` as you are getting error for that particular missing function.

Comment: Make sure all the plugins are properly active. Also you can try deactivating plugins one by one to check if any of the plugin is causing the problem.

Comment: I have detected the plugin that is giving the problem, but if I disable it the web does not work because it is a tool created by that company. On the server it works correctly but when moving it to my new server it does not work (that error appears)